# parsing xml with php - getting attributes within an array

Tags: php, xml

i have some xml that I am trying to parse with php with the following code:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file($file_path)
foreach ($data as $obj):
   //get author, date, etc
   ...
            // get the paths
            foreach ($obj->paths as $current):
                $kind = $current['kind'];
                $action = $current['action'];
                $path = $current->path;
```

but I cannot get the kind and action attributes for some reason... the path will work, but not the attributes

the xml looks like this:

```
<log>

<logentry
   revision="xxxx">
    <author>xyz</author>
    <date>my date</date>
    <paths>
       <path
          kind="file"
          action="M">/myPath/woohoo</path>
       <path.... *more paths*
    ....more logentries
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making use of the right approach to access the attributes (write it like accessing an array with string-keys representing the name of the attribute), however you're doing it on the wrong element:

```
$root = simplexml_load_file($path);

foreach ($root->logentry->paths as $current)
{
    $path   = $current->path;
    $kind   = $path['kind'];
    $action = $path['action'];
}
```

As this example shows, you need to access the attributes on `$path` and not on `$current`. That's all. You probably have just over-looked that because the `$path` variable was already in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$current->attributes()` to get them.